# by viewModel in Adapter class not found

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel

I want to use my Viewmodel instance in Adapter class but it doesn't find the viewModel delegate.It works in fragment and activities but not found in adapter classes.

```
   private val queueViewModel: QueueViewModel by viewModels {
    QueueViewModel.QueueDataViewModelFactory((requireActivity().application as DownloadManagerApplication).repository)
}
```

unresolved reference: viewModels

Comment: There isn't a method `Adapter.viewModels`. You might want to read more about what a view model is (especially about it's scope and lifecycle), because it doesn't make any sense to have a view model scoped to an adapter.

Comment: The ViewModel lifecycle is >= than the Adapter's lifecycle, so you could theoretically pass the instance of the ViewModel to its constructor. But if you need the ViewModel inside an Adapter, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: `DownloadManagerApplication` you probably wat to download something, so the most common pattern is to keep the view model on the host fragment and then when the user clicks a row on the adapter a callback is triggered from the adapter to the host fragmen and then the host fragment triggers the view model work.